# How do i detect collision between 2 rectangles??? LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

So I have this problem that the Rectangle.overlaps isn't working for some reason or I don't know.
All this does is it draws a jet (MyActor) and a bullet Actor and on touch it makes the bullet move towards the blue enemy Actor and i want it to System.out.println("touched"); if bullet hits the enemy.

I'll just paste the whole code.

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener{

private Texture texture;
private Texture bulletTexture;
private Texture enemyTexture;
private MyActor myActor;
private BulletActor bulletActor;
private EnemyActor enemyActor;
private Stage stage;
private BackGroundActor backGroundActor;

private Rectangle bulletRectangle;

private Rectangle enemyRectangle;
float X=500,Y =600;

float bulletX = X, bulletY = Y+43;
float enemyX =0, enemyY = 615;
boolean started;
int touched = 0;

public class EnemyActor extends Actor{

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        batch.draw(enemyTexture,enemyX,enemyY);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        if(bulletRectangle.overlaps(enemyRectangle)){
            System.out.println("Overlaps");
        }
    }
}

public class BackGroundActor extends Actor{
    public BackGroundActor() {
        setBounds(0,0,1280,720);
        addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                started = true;
                touched++;
                System.out.println(touched);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

public class MyActor extends Actor{
    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        batch.draw(texture,X,Y);
    }
}

public class BulletActor extends Actor{

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        batch.draw(bulletTexture,bulletX,bulletY);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        if(started) {
            bulletX -= 3;
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void create() {

    texture = new Texture("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\LibGdxMainProjects\\SampleGame1\\android\\assets\\0001.png");
    bulletTexture = new Texture("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\LibGdxMainProjects\\SampleGame1\\android\\assets\\bullet.png");
    enemyTexture = new Texture("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\LibGdxMainProjects\\SampleGame1\\android\\assets\\fuel.png");

    bulletRectangle = new Rectangle(bulletX,bulletY,bulletTexture.getWidth(),bulletTexture.getHeight());
    enemyRectangle = new Rectangle(enemyX,enemyY,enemyTexture.getWidth(),enemyTexture.getHeight());

    stage = new Stage();
    myActor = new MyActor();
    enemyActor = new EnemyActor();
    bulletActor = new BulletActor();
    backGroundActor = new BackGroundActor();
    backGroundActor.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

    stage.addActor(bulletActor);
    stage.addActor(myActor);
    stage.addActor(backGroundActor);
    stage.addActor(enemyActor);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();

    if(enemyRectangle.overlaps(bulletRectangle)){
        System.out.println("HIT I SAY");
    }

}

@Override
public void resize ( int width, int height){

}

@Override
public void pause () {

}

@Override
public void resume () {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the `bulletRectangle` is not updated with the new position of the bullet, `bulletX` is not directly linked to `bulletRectangle`.

You could do

```
if(started) {
    bulletX -= 3;
    bulletRectangle.setX(bulletX);
}
```

You might want also to update the other rectangle with the proper position of the enemy

Answer (score 0):

According to the [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html), there is a method [`intersects(Rectangle r)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects(java.awt.Rectangle)). You can use this to determine whether two rectangles intersect. Take a look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.awt/Rectangle/Java_Rectangle_intersects_Rectangle_r_.htm).

Comment: This is not the same Rectangle as libGDX [Rectangle](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html#overlaps-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(enemyRectangle.overlaps(bulletRectangle)){
    System.out.println("HIT I SAY");
}
```

add this code in your update method